# apache2 rotatelogs creates log file but its empty when deployed to azure web app

Tags: azure, logging, web-applications, apache2, logrotate

im trying to rotatelogs by day, i've setup the following in apache conf. file:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs -l /var/log/apache2/lat.%Y.%m.%d.log 86400" common
```

this works locally for some reason, but when I deploy the container on azure's app service, all it does is creates the log file: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root        0 Mar 28 21:41 lat.2024.03.28.log`
but it remains 0 byte, wont write anything into it. Even if i give write permission, wont change a thing.
Any guess what else I should check?